# Initialising Firebase Crashlytics in an iOS common project shared by other projects

Tags: ios, crashlytics

I have an iOS project with common functionality (including FB Crashlytics logging) included in several other iOS projects each with their own GoogleService-Info.plist file.

Everything seemed to work fine until it came to adding the "Firebase/FirebaseCrashlytics/run" Run Script phase to the common project at which point I find I need to pass in the correct GoogleService-Info.plist file (via /FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols).

Is there a way to do this, perhaps some way to detect the project containing the common project  and set the correct path to the appropriate GS-I.plist file, or will I have to move all FB functionality into the separate projects?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I put the Run Script into my separate projects but referenced the FB path in the common project, e.g.

"../CommonProject/Firebase/FirebaseCrashlytics/run"

I assume this will work (there's no errors on compilation, obviously) but have yet to confirm FB logging, etc... occurs.